# Problem getting data with LINQ in C# from localdb

Tags: c#, list, linq

Im working on a web service that uses a database (for developing i use the built-in vs localdb) to fill a data structure which i wrote (data structure works fine, the project has been going on for a while).

I have 3 classes: Instance, Token and Variables (just a list of strings actually, for testing):

- Instance
  Name:string
  ModelId:string
  Tokens: List
- DbToken
  Id:Int
  Instance:DbInstance
  Position:string
  Variables: List
- DbVariable
  Id:string
  Name:string
  Value:string

The database has 3 tables: Instance (which is the main one), Tokens and Variables.

I want to get a List of all the **Instance** objects stored in the database, so I need to get every object in Instance and include the data from **tokens** and **variables**. Its not a problem with the data structure or the database, its most likely just a lack of understanding LINQ (havent worked with LINQ alot and its kinda difficult to me) because i have other functions accessing the database e.g. for single instance objects and they work.

There is data in the tables and during debugging, i can see it in the tables (wanted to post screenshots but i dont have 10 rep yet)

This is how i currently try to get all instances:

`var getList = GovContext.Instance.Include(a => a.ModelId == model.Name).Include(b => b.Tokens).ToList();`

What is the correct query to retrieve a List of all Instances in the database? (This already works for single Instance objects btw, which is another function).

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if i can improve my way of asking questions please let me know :)

Comment: LINQ Include will take only the navigation property name, but how come a condition? `Include(a => a.ModelId == model.Name)`

Comment: ```GovContext.Instance.Where(a => a.ModelId == model.Name).Include(b => b.Tokens).ToList()``` should do the trick.

Comment: Nope, that doesnt work unfortunately. getList is still empty

Comment: With ```.Where(x => x.Name == "Test")``` you filter all Instance objects with the predicate in the Where clause. In this example all Instance objects that have the name "Test" will be returned. If you want all Instance objects without filtering just omit ```.Where()```. As example: ```GovContext.Instance.Include(b => b.Tokens).ToList()```.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but looking at documentation, `.Include()` accepts a string argument, not a predicate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Jacob JA Shanks it accepts both "magic" strings and predicate. Makes more sense to use predicate.

Comment: @JacobJAShanks The [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include%60%602);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.1) accepts a predicate.

Comment: @Rabban Actually i tried getList = GovContext.Instance.Where().ToList() and not even that works. Instance has Members from other classes, do i have to include them? I thought if i dont it just nulls them

Comment: @QuestGamer7 Omit ```.Where()``` not ```.Include()```. You need Include to access your Tokens from the Instance object.

Comment: @Rabban Oh yeah, makes sense :D Atleast i can get the 2 existing objects with `GovContext.Instance.Include(a => a.Tokens).ToList()`

Comment: @QuestGamer7 Does it work now like you want?

Comment: @Rabban No. I tried the same string just with a `Where(a => a.ModelId == model.Name)`before the Include but still get both instances (they have different models ??

Comment: @Rabban Nvm. I restarted it and now it works as intended. Thanks!

One more little question: I answered my Post with the solution to show it to other ppl. Ist that the correct form of doing it in StackOverflow or should i put the Solution in my original question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now works as intended:

```
var getList = GovContext.Instance.Where(a => a.ModelId == model.Name)
             .Include(b => b.Tokens).ToList()
```

Comment: It's the correct way to add a answer if you can answer it by yourself. Just mark it as Answer and you have successful finished your first question on StackOverflow. Btw. Welcome to SO ;)

Comment: @Rabban Thank you very much :D  and thanks for your help!

Sadly i have to wait 2 days before i can mark it as answer, but i guess there is some reason behind this. Looking forward to my next question :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at this (and I'm also relatively new at replying to questions) but try:

```
var models = GovContext.Instances.AsQueryable();
models = models.Include(b => b.Tokens)
var list = models.FirsOrDefault(a => a.ModelId == model.Name);
```

Comment: "FirstorDefault" only returns a single object.Well this might work for single Instances, but i already have a working query for single Instances in another function:
`GovContext.Instance.Include(inst => inst.Tokens).Where(inst => inst.Name == instanceId && inst.ModelId == modelId).FirstOrDefault()`